# iPhone MapView - can I clear the cache of the map?

Tags: iphone, caching, mapkit

I am working on an iPhone app that uses a MKMapView inside of a view controller.
I am doing requests to a server for events on the current displayed region on the map. The requests are done every time the user moves the map(or zooms) - in the regionDidChangeAnimated.

I noticed that after moving in the same area of the map, the regionDidChangeAnimated is not called anymore. It seems that the caching of the map might cause this to happen.
If the user zooms in or out, regionDidChangeAnimated is called again. If the user returns to the zoom level where the method is not called, the bad/strange behaviour continues.

I do not know where else should I do the requests, as I need to update the map with annotations every time the user changes the displayed region.

I would really appreciate your advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
```

Comment: I did add the code suggested in my AppDelegate class, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, as I understood it must be called before I create any instance of the MKMapView. The behaviour continues on an iPhone 4, but I did not have it yet on my development iPhone, which is a 3GS. This does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I do not know where should I place the code suggested by you, other than in AppDelegate.